# How to send some specific info in Header and some info in Body in a single JSON response, for a GET request in Spring boot?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

In my Spring boot project, I have made **AuthController** class, where I have written the code for making Sign-in POST request and in response, I show the **jwt token** generated by this successful Sign-in request.

Here's the code of my **AuthController class**-

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                    loginRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtAuthenticationResponse(jwt));
}
```

And here's the response I get, when the sign-in request is successful-

```
{
  "accessToken": "abcd",
  "tokenType": "Bearer"
}
```

**----Now the Problem is---**

I need to do something different. I want this **accessToken** to send in response **HEADER** rather than the **response Body**. **In response Body**, I want to send the **UserId** and **email** in a **JSON** response. I am not having any idea how to do that. So, It would be nice if someone help me to do that with an example code or making some changes in the code I have given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `HttpServletResponse` to add response headers.

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest,
                                          HttpServletResponse response) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    loginRequest.getUsernameOrEmail(),
                    loginRequest.getPassword()
            )
    );

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);

    // set headers here
    response.addHeader("accessToken", jwt);      
    response.addHeader("tokenType", "Bearer");

    JwtAuthenticationResponse response = new JwtAuthenticationResponse();
    response.setUserId(/*userId here*/);
    response.setEmail(/*email here*/);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

And in your `JwtAuthenticationResponse` add `userId` and `email` fields, or just use another class.

```
public class JwtAuthenticationResponse {

    private Long userId;
    private String email;

    //getters setters
}
```